# logging in Django test with verbosity

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm looking for a way to write to console only when Django tests are run with high verbosity level.
For example - when I run

```
python manage.py test -v 3
```

It would log my messages to console, but, when I run

```
python manage.py test -v 0
```

It would not log my messages.

I tried to use `logger.info()` in the code but the messages do not show up at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`-v` controls the verbosity of the test runner itself (eg: DB creation, etc), not the verbosity of your app's logging.

What you actually want, is to change the logging level of the django app itself, as described in the [logging documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#examples).

You may want to simply override the logging settings just for tests, or you can use `--debug-mode` to set `settings.DEBUG` to `True`, and include a DEBUG-specific configuration in your settings.py (this is rather common since it also helps when developing).

This is a basic example of how to achieve the latter:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'sentry'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'myapp': {
        'level': 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```